# Qt Creator Debugging

Tags: windows, debugging, qt

I'm using QT Creator on 3 platforms to create platform independent software. However, I'm getting a segmentation fault with the exact same code in Windows only. That doesn't sound so bad because I can use the debugger. Except, no matter how many breakpoints I set or where I set them, they are ignored by the debugger. I am 100% sure that my control flow is going through the breakpoint but not breaking the flow.

Any thoughts? How can that happen?

Comment: @CJ: did you try compile code with *VS 2008 + Qt library* build? For me debugging work great with studio.

Answer (score 2):

Doh! I was using Cmake with Qt and I failed to set the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable. That was it!